# Navigation Component implicit deeplink with backstack

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have three screens. A, B and C.

A -> B -> C

What I want is that when I navigate to C with implicit deeplink (e.g. with a url), when back button is pressed, app goes to B, not A.